# Draw the interested point on the map and save the point attribute to OpenGIS database

Tags: web-mapping, editing

I am looking for a map solution can help me pinpoint the wireless route location on my organization's indoor map. I have an indoor map server on which Geoserver is running.

I have found an example page http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/editingtoolbar.html which allows you to draw a point on the map. I also need to edit this point and add attributes for that point such as "Wifi Router Label", "Mac address" etc and save these attributes to PostGIS database so I can have my wireless route geo-location data.

I am lack of javascript knowledge and would like to know which company or person I can contact to get this task done? Or you can post your suggestions here and your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micello can provide the hosted map and SDK to achieve this. Checkout micello.com and feel free to reach out.

Comment: Thanks, Anil. This community feels it is important for people connected to products to clearly identify themselves when recommending them: otherwise such posts are taken as spam and are treated rather harshly.